# Permission returning false even when allowed

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I am checking if my application have access to camera and to write external storage, but the first time when I am asked for permission even after giving them the app still return false, Here is my code

```
   private fun getPermission(): Boolean {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if( (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )&&
            checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true
        } else {
            requestPermissions(listOf(CAMERA, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).toTypedArray(), 1)

        }
    }
return false

}
```

so if, I use this function getPermission it will first time return false (on screen I am allowing my application to access camera and storage ) and on next turn (I go back to home activity and again open this Camera activity) this time I am not asked for permissions and my application starts using camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in @Marko answer all I was missing was onRequestPermissionsResult callback, here is the code:

```
 //the is a overridden method
 override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if(requestCode==1){
        if(grantResults[0]==PERMISSION_DENIED && grantResults[1]== PERMISSION_DENIED){
            AlertDialogBox().createBuilder(this,"Permission","Camera and Storage permission denied","ok")
        }else if(grantResults[1]== PERMISSION_DENIED){
            AlertDialogBox().createBuilder(this,"Permission","Storage permission denied","ok")
        }else if(grantResults[0]== PERMISSION_DENIED){
            AlertDialogBox().createBuilder(this,"Permission","Camera permission denied","ok")
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question perfectly describes the specified behavior. The method `requestPermissions` orders the system to:

1. pause your activity
2. start a system-provided activity that asks the user for permissions
3. resume your activity
4. call its `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback

The call to `requestPermissions` returns immediately after setting up this procedure on the system side.

Comment: Yes, logically speaking the flow is good but how can set my method to return true if user gives permission,

Comment: At the moment the user sees the prompt, not only has your method long completed, your activity is no longer active. Clearly, the method can't return the outcome of the user's interaction with the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below lines in the manifest file may it helps you in resolving the issue.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```